# Using Fold Method In Flutter Web Doesnt Work

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a fold method and sort that works in Flutter for mobile but, doesnt work in the web version. When I call on my home page, this is the error I get:

> FutureBuilder 
>       lib/…/HomePage/Home.dart:356
>       When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
>       packages/BuddiesWebApp/Pages/HomePage/Home.dart.lib.js 3503:35  [_getProductsInHeadings]
>       packages/BuddiesWebApp/Pages/HomePage/Home.dart.lib.js 3640:70  
>       packages/flutter/src/widgets/async.dart.lib.js 517:77                                         build

This is my Filter method:

```
  List<ProductsInHeading> _getProductsInHeadings(List<Product> items) {
    switch (selectedTab) {
      case FilterTabs.Feels:
        final Map<String, List<Product>> allFeelings =
            Map.fromEntries(TabCategories.feeling.map((e) => MapEntry(e, [])));

        Map<String, List<Product>> headingItems =
            items.fold(allFeelings, (feelings, element) {
          if (!feelings.containsKey(element.effect)) {
            return feelings;
          }

          return feelings
            ..update(element.effect, (value) => value..add(element));
        });
        productList = headingItems;
        print("headingItems: $headingItems");

        return headingItems.entries
            .map((e) => ProductsInHeading(e.key, e.value..sort()))
            .toList()
              ..sort()
              ..where((e) => e.products.length != 0);
        break;



  case FilterTabs.Rec:
    final Map<String, List<Product>> allRecommended =
        Map.fromEntries(recCategories.map((e) => MapEntry(e, [])));

    Map<String, List> headingItems =
        items.fold(allRecommended, (feeling, element) {
      if (!feeling.containsKey(element.effect)) {
        return feeling;
      }

      return feeling
        ..update(recCategories.toString(), (value) => value..add(element));
    });
    productList = headingItems;
    print("headingItems: $headingItems");

    return headingItems.entries
        .map((e) => ProductsInHeading(e.key, e.value..sort()))
        .toList()
          ..sort()
          ..where((e) => e.products.length != 0);
    break;



      case FilterTabs.Relief:
        // usage might be wrong, I'm not sure
        final Map<String, List<Product>> allRecovery =
            Map.fromEntries(TabCategories.usage.map((e) => MapEntry(e, [])));

        Map<String, List<Product>> headingItems =
            items.fold(allRecovery, (recovery, element) {
          if (!recovery.containsKey(element.usage)) {
            return recovery;
          }

          return recovery
            ..update(element.usage, (value) => value..add(element));
        });
        productList = headingItems;

        // print("headingItems: $headingItems");
        return headingItems.entries
            .map((e) => ProductsInHeading(e.key, e.value..sort()))
            .toList()
              ..sort();
        break;
      case FilterTabs.Categories:
        // usage might be wrong, I'm not sure
        final Map<String, List<Product>> allCategories = Map.fromEntries(
            TabCategories.prodCategory.map((e) => MapEntry(e, [])));

        Map<String, List<Product>> headingItems =
            items.fold(allCategories, (categories, element) {
          if (!categories.containsKey(element.productCategory)) {
            return categories;
          }

          return categories
            ..update(element.productCategory, (value) => value..add(element));
        });

        // print("headingItems: $headingItems");
        productList = headingItems;

        return headingItems.entries
            .map((e) => ProductsInHeading(e.key, e.value..sort()))
            .toList()
              ..sort()
              ..where((e) => e.products.length != 0);
        break;

      case FilterTabs.All:
        return TabCategories.all
            .map((e) => ProductsInHeading(e, items))
            .toList();
    }
    throw UnsupportedError("Unsupported tab type");
  }
```

I'm not sure how to migrate this properly. Please help